# javascript object properties vs public methods

Tags: javascript, performance, methods, properties

If I have a javascript class in which I wish to expose a method, is it better to expose the method using the this keyword (ie to make it publicly accessible in an unqualified way either using this or object.prototype.method, or to define an object property using object.defineProperty?

I would like to know any performance implications that you might know about, including speed and/or footprint.  Obviously in object.defineProperty, I have the ability to control access to the property, and thus to any method that it exposes, although I am limited to only one parameter per method.  However,  if use a method, then I can create the access control more flexibly, so encapsulation is not really an issue, but given that object.defineProperty is a language feature and allows me to use the revealing pattern, I wonder if there are any performance implications.

Many thanks for your input...

Comment: Consider using typescript, it will make classes a lot easier to work with, much more readable and you don't have to learn a new language because it is fully compatible with plain javascript. It will solve your problem by just adding 'private' or 'public' before your method.

Comment: I've literally just found typescript a few days ago and will be using it for projects from now on (I used to program a lot in actionscript so its great!) but before I do and since I am relearning base language concepts I thought I would find out if anyone knows.

Comment: Its really the performance implications that I am interested in, since I am writing some animation code and I would like to know if being a language feature, one can adjust access to properties in a more efficient way in a time critical situation rather than the overhead of a method call.   So if anyone knows how the compiler/interpreter works or has run timed experiments.  I may head over to codepen or similar and try that now.

Comment: It seems from a quick look that methods are faster than object properties at least where a parameter is passed.